# Tramp hangs after sending password

Tags: emacs, emacs24, plink, tramp

I am trying to SSH using plink.exe in Emacs Tramp. I've downloaded the plink.exe which works in a normal terminal but when I use

C-x C-f

```
/gg88@afs1.njit.edu:/afs/cad/u/g/g/gg88/public_html/index.html
```

In the minibuffer,

```
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell also appears.
```

c:/Users/name/emacs-24.3/bin where plink.exe is located is in exec-path. My .emacs contains only these lines. But after checking exec-path does contain the directory plink.exe is in.

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "plink")
```

There is also no problem using M-x eshell, going to c:/Users/name/emacs-24.3/bin, and running

```
plink.exe gg88@afs1.njit.edu
```

What can I do next to get this working?

**Edit**
    Got plink to be recognized by adding the path to plink directly to the PATH variable but still have the

```
 Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell also appears.
```

problem

**Edit2 Messages buffer**

```
Tramp: Opening connection for gg88@afs1.njit.edu using plink...
Tramp: Sending command `plink -l gg88  -ssh afs1.njit.edu && exit || exit'

Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending Password
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell [7 times]
Tramp: Sending command `plink -l gg88  -ssh afs1.njit.edu && exit || exit'
Tramp: Opening connection for gg88@afs1.njit.edu using plink...done
Quit [2 times]
```

Comment: OT1H you say "I've added the directory where plink.exe is located to exec-path" but OTOH you show your .emacs which doesn't touch exec-path.  Which is it?  BTW, Tramp is enabled by default, so you don't need `(require 'tramp)`.

Comment: I used (add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Users/name/emacs24-3/bin") where plink.exe is in bin. It's not in the .emacs but when I check its value with C-h v exec-path, that path is still there.

Comment: Finally got plink to be recognized by adding it to the PATH variable instead but Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell also appears. is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

First I have plink.exe in my `~/.emacs.d/bin`

and then I wrap everything in a `runemacs.bat` file in my `emacs-24` directory:

```
SET HOME=D:\\benoit
SET PATH=%PATH%;%HOME%\.emacs.d\bin
start %CD%\bin\runemacs.exe
```

And it works.
Sometimes emacs for windows / tramp / putty / whatever messes, so I run `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` to get a fresh start. `tramp` bundled with emacs 24.2 is OK, but the one with 24.3 is buggy so you may need to update it manually.

Comment: I tried this solution but the message "Tramp:Waiting for prompts from remote shell" still appears. I think the problem instead may have to do with the regex that looks for the login prompt.